# Call to a member function store() on null enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: laravel

I was working on a college assignment but I had problems in uploading pictures.

even though, I already used  enctype="multipart/form-data" but still can't upload data

the result if I include images will produce a blank white page, but if not the qrud runs smoothly

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Function inside the controller

```
 public function update(ProfilEditRequest $request) {

    $data = $request->all();

    if (isset($data['avatar'])) {
        $isImg = explode(".",  $data['avatar']);

        if ($isImg[sizeof($isImg)-1] == "png" ||
        $isImg[sizeof($isImg)-1] == "jpg" ||
        $isImg[sizeof($isImg)-1] == "jpeg" ||
        $isImg[sizeof($isImg)-1] == "svg"  ) {

            $path = $request->file($data['avatar'])->store('/public/assets/profil-img/'.Auth::user()->id.'/');

            $itemss =DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->update([
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'img_url' => $data['avatar']
            ]);
        }else {
                return redirect('/profile/');
        }

        $item = user::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
        $item->update($data);

        return redirect('/');
        }

        $itemss =DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->update([
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'name' => $data['name']
        ]);

        return redirect('/sell/');
    }
```

here my html form

```
  <form method="GET" action="{{url('profil/update/')}}"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    @csrf  
    <!--input type="number" value=""><br>-->
    <label for="email" >email</label><br>
    <input type="email" size="60" name="email" value="{{Auth::user()->email}}" required>  <br><br>

    <label for="name">nama</label><br>
    <input type="text" size="60" name="name" min="1" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}" required><br><br>

    <label for="avatar">Select new profil picture</label>
    <input type="file"
    name="avatar" id="avatar" width="48" height="48"> <br><br><br>

    <input class="btn btn-primary"type="submit">
    <a href="{{url('/profil/')}}" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: do you change the `Request` method? if not then change `ProfilEditRequest $request` to `Request $request`

Comment: you may want to use `POST` not `GET` for the form method ... your input would be `avatar` not the value of the `avatar` field : `$request->file('avatar')` not `$request->file($data['avatar'])`

Comment: thanks for your advice, now this works

Answer (score 0):

in order to debug such case you have to monitor your code in each step to see where exactly the error is, so you can get the result of each code line by something like `dd($whatever_want_to see)`

if you were run `$request->file($data['avatar'])` will see it's value and know here is my fault

and as mentioned in the comments try something like

```
 public function update(Request $request) {

    $data = $request->all();

    if (isset($request->file('avatar'))) {
        $isImg = explode(".",  $data['avatar']);

        if ($isImg[sizeof($isImg)-1] == "png" ||
           $isImg[sizeof($isImg)-1] == "jpg" ||
           $isImg[sizeof($isImg)-1] == "jpeg" ||
           $isImg[sizeof($isImg)-1] == "svg"  ) {

                  $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('/public/assets/profil-img/'.Auth::user()->id.'/');

           //rest of your code
```